# Sorting drop down

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am populating a dropdown with unique values from a csv file, but the values are not sorted. 
I tried using the listname.sort() but I get this error message:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

The code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data/ItemList.csv', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")
options = []
for item in df['Item Name'].unique():
    options.append({'label':str(item),'value':item})
soptions = options.sort()

html.Div([
    html.H3('Select crime :', style={'paddingRight':'30px'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my_crime_picker',
        options=soptions,
        value=['Burglery'],
        multi=True
    )
], style={'display':'inline-block', 'verticalAlign':'top', 'width':'30%'})
```

I'm hoping this is an easy one for Python gurus.

Comment: First, `sort()` is in-place so you shouldn't assign the result back (though you've deleted that line in an edit) and second, you can pass a `key` parameter to the `sorted()` function to access dictionary keys

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `options` like this:

```
options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Item Name'].unique().sort_values()]
```

So your modified code would be:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data/ItemList.csv', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")

html.Div([
    html.H3('Select crime :', style={'paddingRight':'30px'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my_crime_picker',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Item Name'].unique().sort()],
        value=['Burglary'],
        multi=True
    )
], style={'display':'inline-block', 'verticalAlign':'top', 'width':'30%'})
```

Comment: Getting this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CrimeAppCallback2.py", line 50, in <module>
    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Item Name''].unique().sort_values()],
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

I'm running Python 3.6.7, Pandas 0.22.0 if that's an issue.

Comment: My fault, you need `sort()` not `sort_values()` since `unique()` returns a numpy array, not a `pd.Series()`

Comment: Getting new error:
python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

My understanding is this means there's a null value in the dataframe, so is there a quick way for it to ignore null values?

I tried:

cl = df['Crime Code Description'].unique()
options = []
for item in cl: #df['Item Name'].sort_values():
    options.append({'label':str(item ),'value':item })

        options= options.sort() 
But this returns the error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: Could you please update your OP with what you tried and the new error you are getting? Hard to discern in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sorted(df['Item Name'].unique())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.